# Stop wordpress changing my shortcode block?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some shortcodes in the `index.html` template eg: `<!-- wp:shortcode -->[header]<!-- /wp:shortcode -->`

The shortcode adds a bunch of html and php between an `ob_start()` and `return ob_get_clean()`.

This worked nicely until just recently (I am assuming a wordpress update) when it started inserting `<br>` and empty `<p></p>` tags all throughout.

How can I prevent this happening?

I have tried adding `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );` at the top of my `functions.php` as some answers suggest, but this does nothing.

Comment: My guess is it is related to this: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/58333

Comment: @ChrisHaas, that link refers to a different issue, where shortcodes in templates weren't working at all.

Comment: @nydame, if you read all the way to [comment 102](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/58333#comment:102) you'll see that the _fix_ that WordPress applied to address the template issue is now being reported as introducing what the OP reported

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the familiar "the_conent" filter hook isn't going to do anything. If you look at the wp-includes/shortcodes.php file, you'll see how shortcode output is rendered. In particular, the output is put through wpautop() and there's no good way I can think of to stop this from happening. [Note: I am working with WordPress v6.2.2, so this observation may eventually become obsolete.]

How to solve the problem? I've been wrestling with it for a while and at this point I can think of 2 approaches that **should** work.

1. Put the shortcode block in its own template part and tell your client to never, ever edit it. (What could possibly go wrong?)
2. Create a custom shortcode block where you control what happens when someone hits "save" in the block editor by writing your own save.js file.